# Normal Contact Force of Acting on Two Posts

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

$\textbf{Question A.}$
A goal frame has a mass $100\,\textrm{kg}$, and has two identical posts $p_1$ and $p_2$ and a uniform crossbar. Respective contact forces $r_1$ and $r_2$ act vertically on the two posts. Find $r_1$.

$r_1=r_2$ since the crossbar if uniform.

Since the frame is in equilibrium $r_1+r_2=2r=100\,\mathrm{g};\, r=50\times 9.81=490.5\,\textrm{N}$

---

$\textbf{Question B.}$ If a mass of $75\,\textrm{kg}$ hangs $2\,\textrm{m}$ from $p_1$ and the crossbar length is $7\,\textrm{m}$ what are the values of $r_1$ and $r_2$?

Using moments

$\begin{align}
\tau_1&=2\times75\times9.81+\frac{7}{2}\times100\times9.81-r_1\\
&=4905-r_1
\end{align}$

and

$
\begin{align}
\tau_2&=5\times75\times9.81+\frac{7}{2}\times100\times9.81-r_2\\
&=7112.25-r_2
\end{align}
$

Equilibrium implies

$4905-r_1=7112.25-r_2;\quad r_2-r_1=2207.25$

and

$75\times9.81+100\times9.81=1716.75=r_1+r_2$
which solving gives
$r_2=1962, \quad r_1=-245.75$

---

Are my answers correct?
I feel part B is wrong since I am unsure whether using moments here is allowed, and if the normal contact force is a moment.

I have tried searching Google with terms such as "two pivots mechanics" and "goal post normal contact force", but have not found anything which may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take moments about the points r1 and r2, which then you will get two seperate equations, which is what you have done, and that's fine. Take another look at both of your equations, r1 and r2 are forces and since you are taking moments about both those points, you need to multiply r1 and r2 by their distance. What you have essentially done is equate the moments with the forces, which is incorrect.

Comment: Is the distance to the other pivot then? So for example I should have $4905−r_1\times 7$  where 7m is the distance to the other pivot?  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: yep that's right :)